# How to subscribe to different channels through Action Cable in Rails 5 for logged on and not logged on users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

This example from Rails docs is not suitable, since I need to sign an authorized or not authorized user to a different channel.

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected
      def find_verified_user
        if current_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_id])
          current_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```